# addSubview not showing view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview, addsubview

I'm trying to add a `UITextVIew` to my cell with the following code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("message_cell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DisplayMessageCollectionViewCell

    let messageTextView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)
        textView.text = chat_m[indexPath.row].text
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return textView
    }()
    cell.addSubview(messageTextView)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    return cell
```

The problem is it is not visible on screen. Previously I have added it using the storyboard, however this problem occurred : [UITextView in CollectionView Wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498316/uitextview-in-collectionview-wrapping)

Comment: what type of cell is your interface builder cell? Because if **it isn't custom** you cant add custom textviews

Comment: Use the Visual Debugger to find the subview. You may need to bring the added view to the front. Also, your code will continually add textviews to a CollectionView cell each time the cell is re-used. I strongly suggest you go back to using the Storyboard.

Comment: @Eric are you referring to DisplayMessageCollectionViewCell?

Comment: @RoboticCat I would like to go back to the storyboard but I am unable to solve the issue I had there in the linked question

Comment: Why do you suppose adding a subview in code with no constraints will be any different? You have taken a minor issue (not adjusting your constraints correctly) and created a major issue (adding views in code that constantly re-add everytime the cell is reused). My advice is to use the tools Apple has given you but it is up to you.

Comment: Yes, and then look where you create the cell and look for the "Style" @Mankee

Comment: @RoboticCat can you help me adjust the constraints correctly as I still don't know what I did wrong there

Comment: Look at the comments on that question - there is an answer there.

Comment: I tried it, it's wrong